# Why React doesn't render the list item?

Tags: reactjs

Could you please look at this simple React component and tell me Why the list items don't show? There is no error in the console and the console.log(index, item) works too.
But React doesn't render the list item.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
  };

  getList = () => {
    this.state.tags.map((item, index) => {
      console.log(index, item);
      return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.getList()}</ul>;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: getList doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gitList() is not returning anything. Try the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
  };

  getList = () => {
    return this.state.tags.map((item, index) => {
      console.log(index, item);
      return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.getList()}</ul>;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Alternatively, you could also do this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
  };

  getList = () => this.state.tags.map((item, index) => {
    console.log(index, item);
    return <li key={index}>{item}</li>;
  });

  render() {
    return <ul>{this.getList()}</ul>;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```